# What happens between double-click in file manager and application launch?

Tags: debian, application, freedesktop, file-manager

What is the chain of apps involved in process of opening a file
from a file manager?

Consider these two moments, say it's Xfce 4 and a simple plain
text file set up to open in Mousepad:

1. I hit double-click the file in Thunar or Nautilus etc.,
2. Mousepad is launched with the file

The background is that I have a bug which seems to happen even
when I use different file manager as well as application.  For
example,  Nautilus/Mousepad or Thunar/Libreoffice Calc scenarios
suffer from this bug as well.

It's Debian Jessie amd64, FTM.

Comment: Could you clarify a little? What is this bug? What do you mean by using a "different app for A as well as Z"? Do you mean a bug when you double click in any file manager and open a file in the associated program?

Comment: @terdon Yes, I mean double-click in a FM. I have clarified the Q as well as removed the A and Z, thanks for feedback.

Comment: For @terdon and other curious people, the bug: having utf8 as default, when you open a non-utf8 text file in Mousepad such that causes a Unicode error, MP opens a dialog asking you to select proper encoding.  Now the bug is that not resolving (cancel / choose encoding) the dialog in ~30s, causes the same file be opened again, resulting in 2 such dialogs (but not 3, etc. by extended waiting---it stops at 2).  I can't be sure it's MP since part of observed details happen with Calc as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out what's going on behind the scenes of an application by using the tool `strace`. Simply invoke the tool in question like so:

```
 $ strace <app>
```

Be warned there will be a **lot** of output generated by this tool so you'll likely want to dump it to a file.

```
 $ strace -o <logfile> <app>
```

#### Example

First collect the log.

```
$ strace -o trace.log thunar
```

Once it either crashes or you close it, you can review the logs. Here's a dump of what the log file looks like.

```
$ less trace.log
execve("/usr/bin/thunar", ["thunar"], [/* 93 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x13aa000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7913726000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=243371, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 243371, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f79136ea000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/libX11.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \337\241\3514\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1308808, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x34e9a00000, 3403160, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x34e9a00000
....
```

#### References

- [linux - How to use strace? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174942/how-to-use-strace)
- [7 Strace Examples to Debug the Execution of a Program in Linux - The Geek Stuff](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/11/strace-examples/)
- [5 simple ways to troubleshoot using Strace - Vidar Hokstad](http://www.hokstad.com/5-simple-ways-to-troubleshoot-using-strace)